# Amundsen - borrar / actualizar la información cargada

Tags: python

Estoy dando mis primeros pasos con amundsen.

Hasta el momento, ya tengo la manera de cargar información de los sql server que tengo instalados.

El tema es que no se como hacer para actualizar la información de las bbdd (por ejemplo: si se borra una tabla en sql server, no se como hacer el update de esta novedad)

Alguien sabe como hacerlo?

Lo que uso para cargar la metadata de mis sql server es usar una modificacion del script "sample_mssql_metadata.py"

Comment: Cre que te refieres a los trigers, y podrías poner tu codigo?

Comment: Cristian, lo que pude hacer es METER la informacion en amunsden

Lo que necesito es como borrar lo que ya cargué y como actualizar la info cargada

Comment: Lo siento no puedo ayudarte, no conozco nada de lo que me dices

Comment: Esta parece una pregunta que no versa sobre programación, sino de soporte a usuario final del producto _amundsen_, ¿no?